# How to create autogenerate serial number column in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I want to autopopulate the serial number columns. For eg, the gridview has 10 rows. The user deleted the first row. I want the gridview serial number to automatically shift down by one. Ie., 10-->9, 9-->8 and so on.
Is it possible through javascript.

Can this be done? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you post your gridview code part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this templateField to your `gridView`

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this Template field inside the tag Columns. You will get AutoGenerate SNo.

For More Information see the below link

[How to create autogenerate serial number column in GridView](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/ASPDotNet/how-to-create-autogenerate-serial-number-column-in-gridview.aspx?tdt_pageQueryId=74)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
         CellPadding="5" Style="background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241); width: 50%;">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I hope this helps you. Thanks